# How to verify whether a website is ssl secured or not?

Tags: ssl, web, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I want to find whether the given url(site) is associated with a valid SSL certificate.
Is there any API service provider available. If any, please help me to find.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is on Internet, the best known tool is [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). But it's not an API, only a website that you can request. That said, you can easily automate around openssl.